# F# automatically inlines some functions even thought they are not marked with `inline`, is this intended?

Tags: f#, inline

It appears that F# automatically inlines some functions, even though they are not marked with "inline".

```
let a x= x + 3
let b x= x * x

let funB x y =
    if x > y then 3
    else 1

let funC x =
    let s = a x
    let c = funB s (b x)
    c + 1
```

By inspecting IL, I see the compiler has aggressively inlined `funB` & `a,b`

```
funC:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0003:  add         
IL_0004:  stloc.0     // s
IL_0005:  ldarg.0     
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  mul         
IL_0008:  stloc.1     
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_000A:  ldloc.1     
IL_000B:  ble.s       IL_0011
IL_000D:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  br.s        IL_0013
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0014:  add         
IL_0015:  ret
```

The behaviour looks strange to me. I had thought that the compiler should only inline if there is `inline` keyword. Are there any reference which mentioned it?

Comment: I don't know of any optimizing compiler that *specifically* requires you to use an "inline" keyword to make it capable of optimizing via inlining.

Comment: Only in Release mode, the compiler does this. In Debug mode, there is no inline optimization.

Comment: This looks more like running a 'constant' operation at compile time. An inline version would contain much more code.

Comment: @leppie is right, 'constant folding' is the terminology you're looking for here.

Comment: @leppie I changed my testing code so that the compiler should not do constant folding here.

Comment: @ildjarn I changed my testing code so that the compiler should not do constant folding here.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` keyword is a way of *forcing* the compiler to inline a function and as a result allows a function to take a type as a parameter and increases performance.  There is no reason for the compiler to not inline functions as it sees fit for a release build.