# Is there a maximum depth for F# inlined functions?

Tags: performance, f#, clr, inline

While optimizing at a very busy inner loop -- working on hundreds of millions of floating point numbers -- I used F#'s `inline` to great effect, partly for type genericity, and partly for performance.

By looking at the decompiled IL, it appears that the F# compiler will only inline to a particular depth (perhaps 3 or 4?). If I write my inner loop by hand (two nested `for` loops), I get a the loop with expected conversion code inlined. If instead I write a helper function for the loop so that I can parameterize over word size in the data, the loop contains nested function calls instead, even though all the relevant functions are marked `inline`. This is good for a 2x drop in performance.

I appreciate the `inline` keyword is meant primarily for static type constraints, not performance enhancement, but this behavior surprised me. Is there a maximum amount of work the F# compiler will do to generate inline IL before it gives up? Is there a way to affect this maximum?

(Looking in detail at the code, one should argue that the CLR JIT itself should be inlining the functions, as they are extremely small, mostly some bit shifting and equality tests, but that's another topic entirely.)

Comment: I would guess that `inline` is not doing what you expect - not that there is a limit to max inline depth.  For example, the `^t` constraints actually require inlining, and I think you would be getting an error if that wasn't working.

Comment: Yeah, it's like it's inlining it, but then using partially applied functions that aren't as obvious on inspection, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904557/f-automatically-inlines-some-functions-even-thought-they-are-not-marked-with-i

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if you could include a small repro.